# Arrays comparison (.Txt file to user input) BAT File

Tags: arrays, compare, txt

looking to compare lines of text putting them into an array ( counting the lines in the txt file ) to then compare a user input to the number of lines in the array from the txt file ( I hope that makes sense ) I am confused as to how to do this ?

Thank you for your time and assistance / ideas on this

Comment: @echo off
    FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (new.txt) DO echo %%x
    pause

Comment: that is what I have to read the file but I am looking to put it into some form or array then ask for a user input ... which I know how to do with the set command and then want to compare the input to the lines in the new.txt file